# How do I fix a button command from being executed as soon as the code is run?

Tags: python, function, button, tkinter

I'm trying to get a button to execute a function from another file called validate.py when it's pressed, but the function seems to be executing as soon as I run the code but not when I actually press it?

Button's code:

```
id_validate = ttk.Button(id_frame, text='Validate', 
command=validate.validate(pack_id.get()))
```

And this is the function's code:

```
def validate(pack_id):
    print('vAliDAte')
    return True
```

I want that function to execute every time I click the button and print 'validate' in the console, but it only executes once as soon as I run the code and doesn't respond when the button is pressed.

How do I stop it from executing when the code is run and only execute when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function executes because you call it; ends the function name with parenthesis.

The command attribute only wants the name of the function.

However, you can fix this with lambda:

```
command=lambda: validate(pack_id.get())
```

A warning about using the name pack_id in the function: you already have used that name in the global scope in calling the function with the argument `pack_id.get()`. This might cause problems down the line.